# Nested query microsoft access

Tags: ms-access, subquery

I have a table of transactions. The table was multiple vendors with multiple transactions with multiple transaction amounts. I need to update the table if a vendors transaction is more than double the transaction amount average for that vendor. So far I came up with the following code which is wrong:

```
Update tblTransaction
SET VariabilityIndicator = 1
WHERE transactionNumber IN
(Select transactionNumber
From tblTransaction
GROUP BY VendorName
HAVING transactionAmount >= AVG(transactionAmount*2))
```

The code above is clearly wrong. I came up with a statement that possibly could be nested:

```
SELECT AVG(transactionAmount) VendorName
FROM tblTransaction
GROUP BY VendorName
```

This should return all VendorNames with their average transaction amounts. How can I nest this so I can compare a transactionAmount to the average where the vendor names match??

Answer (score 0):

```
Update tblTransaction
SET VariabilityIndicator = 1
WHERE transactionNumber IN
(
    Select T.TransactionNumber
    from tblTransaction as T
    Where T.transactonAmount > 2 * (
      Select AVG(transactionAmount)
      From tblTransaction as A
      Where A.VendorName = T.VendorName
    )
)
```

You may want to check your business logic to exclude the transactionAmount being evaluated from the average calculation. Also you may not want to match on vendor name, but on some sort of ID number/Primary key value.